# Is my proof correct? (function composition, surjectivity)

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

> **Exercise.** Given sets $E$, $F$, $G$ and functions $g : E \to F$ surjective, and $f : E \to G$. Prove that there's a function $h : F \to G$ such that $f = h \circ g$ **if and only if** the equality $g(x) = g(y)$, with $x, y \in E$, implies the equality $f(x) = f(y)$.

My strategy was the following.

**Right to left.** I assume that $h$ exists. Then if $g(x) = g(y)$, $h(g(x)) = h(g(y))$. Therefore $f(x) = f(y)$ by definition.

**Left to right.** I assume that the equality $g(x) = g(y)$, with $x,y \in E$, implies the equality $f(x) = f(y)$. Given that $g$ is surjective, $g^{-1}(g(E)) = g^{-1}(F) = E$. Therefore $f(g^{-1}\circ g(x)) = f(x)$ [**note**: I know that $f$ and $g$'s values at any given point $x\in E$ have the same preimages, but I don't know how to state this more formally.]. I can then define $h: F \to G$ such that $h(x) = f\circ g^{-1}(x)$, and it verifies the stated condition.

Comment: You are conflating two different meantings of "$g^{-1}$". In your assertion "Given that $g$ is surjective", your use of $g^{-1}$ is for the function associated to **sets**: for each subset $X$ of $F$, $g^{-1}(X)$ is the collection of all $e\in E$ such that $g(e)\in X$. However, when you write $g^{-1}\circ g(x))$, you are using it as a functional inverse that takes elements to elements, and such a function need not exist. There is no "$g^{-1}(x)$", because you do not know that $g$ has an inverse.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Please, have a look at my edit, in order to improve your MathJax-fu.

Answer (score 1):

As Arturo has written in the comment $g$ will not necessary have an inverse. Here's a minimal example: $$E=\{0,1\}\\F=\{0\}\\G=\{0\}$$
In this case, all three functions, $f,g,h$, will be the constant map to $0$ (with different domain/range).
To me, there are two issues in your proof

1. You seem to have only used the surjective property of $g$ but you haven't really used your assumption: $$g(x)=g(y)\Rightarrow f(x)=f(y)$$
2. You even wrote down that you cannot state something more formally (which really is the critical part of the proof)

The idea of your proof is more or less correct, but you will need to define what you are calling $g^{-1}$ into an actual function. You will need to pick a representative and use the $g(x)=g(y)\Rightarrow f(x)=f(y)$ assumption to show that $h$ has the properties needed.